# Save XML to file without generating output?

Tags: php, xml

I'm using a PHP script to generate XML (using the DOMDocument and appending where necessary). At the bottom I use $feed = $dom->saveXML();

Then i use this variable to write to a file with the f* commands. Is there a way of saving the XML to file without outputing the XML to the page. Instead display "file saved" or something along those lines?

```
$xmlString = $dom->saveXML();
echo $xmlString;

$feedFile = fopen("feed.xml", "w"); // Use f* commands to create XML file
fwrite($feedFile, $xmlString);
fclose($feedFile);
```

if i remove the echo it errors with no element found.

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: yes, just don't echo those xml string, and then just `file_put_contents()` it.

Comment: you can use fopen, fwrite and fclose at the same, this page can help you: http://blog.tecnospazio.org/creare-xml-tramite-php-21113, if you give us short code we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `echo $xmlString;` with code that outputs what you want to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The method [DOMDocument::save()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) saves the DOM to a file. It returns `FALSE`on error.

```
if (FALSE === $dom->save($fileName)) {
  // error, not saved
} else {
  // success, file saved
}
```